# Why is the size of alignment for char3 is 1 in CUDA Programming Guide?

Tags: alignment, cuda

I found that alignment for `char1` is 1, for `char2` is 2, for `char3` is 1 and for `char4` is 4.
Why is the alignment size for char3 is 1 instead of 3?

I also need some help to understand the concept of "Alignment Requirements".

Please refer to this [CUDA Programming Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_0/toolkit/docs/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) (Table B-1 of Section B.3.1 in Appendix B)

Many thanks,

Yik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about what would happen if you had an array of `char3` - an alignment of > 1 would mean a non-contiguous array.

For `char4` however you do not have any such padding problems, and you probably want to ensure that a `char4` can be treated as if it were a 32 bit int, so a 4 byte alignment is helpful.

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me why the size of alignment for `char4` is 4 instead of 0?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone like me still getting confused about this problem:
The global memory access is always in size of 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 bytes and so on. So a 3-byte data must be padded to be aligned to achieve high efficiency. If so, then a `char3` is actually a `char4` under the hood, and we are using an extra byte to improve efficiency. Then the alignment is 4.

And there is also another way, which is the way CUDA actually used. Rather than sacrifice space for time, they do the opposite. A `char3` is not a `char4` under the hood, instead, it is 3 `char1`!

With CUDA 11.7 and CC 8.6, I wrote the code below:

```
__device__ char2 ch2[100];
__device__ char3 ch3[100];
__device__ char4 ch4[100];
__global__ void test(char3 chval3,char2 chval2,char4 chval4){
    auto x=threadIdx.x;
    ch3[x]=chval3;
    ch2[x]=chval2;
    ch4[x]=chval4;
}
```

NVCC produced the ptx code as below:

```
ld.param.u8     %rs1, [_Z4test5char35char25char4_param_0+2];
ld.param.u8     %rs2, [_Z4test5char35char25char4_param_0+1];
ld.param.u8     %rs3, [_Z4test5char35char25char4_param_0];
mov.u32     %r1, %tid.x;
mul.wide.u32    %rd1, %r1, 3;
mov.u64     %rd2, ch3;
add.s64     %rd3, %rd2, %rd1;
st.global.u8    [%rd3], %rs3;
st.global.u8    [%rd3+1], %rs2;
st.global.u8    [%rd3+2], %rs1;
mul.wide.u32    %rd4, %r1, 2;
mov.u64     %rd5, ch2;
add.s64     %rd6, %rd5, %rd4;
ld.param.u8     %rs4, [_Z4test5char35char25char4_param_1+1];
ld.param.u8     %rs5, [_Z4test5char35char25char4_param_1];
st.global.v2.u8     [%rd6], {%rs5, %rs4};
mul.wide.u32    %rd7, %r1, 4;
mov.u64     %rd8, ch4;
add.s64     %rd9, %rd8, %rd7;
ld.param.u8     %rs6, [_Z4test5char35char25char4_param_2+3];
ld.param.u8     %rs7, [_Z4test5char35char25char4_param_2+2];
ld.param.u8     %rs8, [_Z4test5char35char25char4_param_2+1];
ld.param.u8     %rs9, [_Z4test5char35char25char4_param_2];
st.global.v4.u8     [%rd9], {%rs9, %rs8, %rs7, %rs6};
ret;
```

We can see that the operations to `char2` and `char4` are compiled to single instructions as `st.global.v2`, `st.global.v4`, while the `char3` is actually treated as 3 `char1`.

So back to the question, why the alignment for `char3` is 1? Because it is 3 `char1` in fact, and no alignment is needed. It is not for padding, on the contrary, the alignment will be 4 if we do the padding here.